# Url query filtering links not working in modern Sharepoint?

Tags: url, query-string

In classic SP tacking a url query onto a page containing a list was a handy way of filtering the content:

```
 page.aspx?FilterField1=<internal field name>&FilterValue1=<value>
```

This no longer works for the modern news web part which is search based. I've tried:

- adding the query to the news.aspx page:/_layouts/15/news.aspx?FilterField1=&FilterValue1=
- creating a new page with an unfiltered news web part on it and creating a link with the above query added to the url

Has anyone found a way to get this to work? The alternative is to manually create  a page with a filtered news web part on it but that doesn't seem very "modern".

Comment: Actually it was bit of a hack. What if you had 2 views of same list on same page in classic SP and you applied URL Filter? It would filter both or conflict or filter just the first? There are reasons why SharePoint has removed certain functionalities in Modern SP

Comment: You can always use a web part page for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @harshalgite Msft themselves are still using it in filtered list view pages so not sure if I'd call it a hack. The news web part uses search so my question is really how to get a url query to work with search.